# ipnoe development ..need to fade text over a back ground image

Tags: iphone, text, fading

i wish to have a lable with text that appears and the slowly fades over a background image.
and have a lable on the image with text but i wish it to stay for i second and then gradualy fade im using xcode and utalising interface builder. thanks

Comment: This is a very poor question. Please spell check and proofread your question before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have a UIImage and UILabel linked from the Interface Builder, place the following in the `viewdidload:` method:

```
// Starting state
myLabel.alpha=0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
// Ending state
myLabel.alpha=1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

// Run another function to fade out after a second
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeOut:) withObject:sender afterDelay:1.0];
```